# Silverlight Plug-In crashed without error

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, mvvm

this is a headache for me to complete my project. I had done my project in Silverlight5 with entity framework. If i run my project in localhost means it worked fine.. but after published my project in server means initial page will run but if i select the next page the Silverlight Plugin gets crashed.. What is the problem here..? Anybody can help me....?

Comment: Are you calling a web service running on a different host? Then you might need a [ClientAccessPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: Turn on the developer tools of your browser and check if any exceptions are thrown

Comment: yeah i had the ClientAccessPolicy file in the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several advices:

- Where do you publish? Check the target and ensure that it has any pre-requisite to run your website
- Publish in a debug mode, and display (or at least log) any unmanaged error in the app.xaml.cs
- Use your browser debug tool (F12 with ie) especially the console output to see any weird message

Answer (score 0):

I put messagebox to check whether the execution is going correctly and fix the error....